# Get privilege before reputation is reached

Tags: support, status-completed

This morning I received a new privilege, but my last upvote was two days ago and in summary I have not reached the "Awarded At"-limit now.

See this screenshot:
[image]

I checked my Reputation history and I the last log was 'yesterday'.
Is there a pending upvote today and the add privilege queue is faster then the "assign upvote"-queue?

Comment: Someone must have upvoted (getting you to 3,500 rep and the privilege) then immediately unupvoted. So, you did get the privilege for a short time. You can see in your reputation page that yesterday you had "no net reputation changes" - this means that all the voting that happened cancelled out (if there were no voting at all, this line wouldn't show up at all).

Comment: That makes sense. I also thought about an upvote and withdraw from some old votings - but I expected to see them in my log. But the immediate unupvote makes sense - when the privilege is assigned immediate and it is not withdrawn when the reputation drops under the limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oded's theory, that someone upvoted then rescinded the upvote, makes the most sense to me.

That's kinda sad though, in a grade-school "Psyche!" kind of way. So I went and found a couple of quite worthy posts of yours and upvoted them. You now really have 3,500+ rep, and should for real be able to protect questions. Use your new power responsibly please.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote ;)